# Preserve trailing zero in excel

Tags: sql, excel, business-intelligence, cognos-8

My field is of character type but displays a decimal. My cognos report output is in excel format and I am trying to retain the trailing zero in my sql. Any suggestions?

I use the following sql to maintain leading zeroes and it works :

'=' + '"' + [Value] + '"'

However, it does not seem to be effective for trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
'=' + '"''' + [Value] + '"'
```

which becomes `="'[Value]"` (note the extra ' in there). Failing that, try

```
'''' + [Value]
```

which becomes `'[Value]`

The extra apostrophe at the beginning tells Excel that the field should be treated as text rather than a number.

Comment: the second method of '''' + [Value] worked for me with Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel).  Thanks!